# How to implement Year for movies in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a `Movie` class that will have a Year property. Should it be just an `int`, or should I use a `DateTime` object?

Just wondering the best option. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 14):

I would probably use an int for simplicity, and make sure that in the setter you verify that the year value makes sense.

Alternatively, you can create a type to just represents years - this would make sure you don't misuse the year as a regular integral value. This gets complicated though, especially if you want to start overloading operators to support year addition and subtraction. Unless you really need this extra level of type safety, I would stick with an int.

Comment: This is consistent with the way a year is represented by `System.DateTime`.  If you are quantifying time, then best use a `System.TimeSpan` or an `System.Globalization.Calendar`.

Answer (score 6):

If it's only going to be a year value, then int will be simpler.  You could also consider just saving the release date as a DateTime, and get the year from that (instead of having a year attribute).

Comment: That's the answer I was about to post. Use an Int unless you also keep track of a release date.

Answer (score 4):

If it's only ever going to be the year then an `int` (or custom type) would do.

If you want to store the month as well then I'd use a `DateTime`.

The Agile mantra - YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) - would suggest an `int` until you want more information and then refactor into a `DateTime` then.

Comment: Thanks by deriving from an int, can you really do this? I didn't know you could have a type that inherits from Int.

Comment: @Joan Venge - you're right. `int` is a `sealed` class. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

use datetime object you can get the year from it like .year well....

Answer (score 1):

Well, DateTime has the unfortunate side-effect of specifying both a data and a time and not only some subsets. Ideally you would probably want some "time" object with varying levels of accuracy, as needed. But for this I'd suggest using an `int` since you are modeling exactly a year, not a complete date.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom type, (a struct) to hold this value.

```
public struct FilmYear
{
   private int yr;
   private bool isDef;
   public bool HasValue { return isDef; }
   public bool IsNull { return !HasValue; }
   private FilmYear(int year) { yr = year; isDef = true; }

   public static FilmYear ThisYear = new FilmYear(DateTime.Today.Year);
   public static FilmYear LastYear = new FilmYear(DateTime.Today.Year - 1);
   public static FilmYear NextYear = new FilmYear(DateTime.Today.Year + 1);
   public static FilmYear Parse(DateTime anyDateInYear)
   { return new FilmYear(anyDateInYear.Year); }
   public static FilmYear Parse(int year)
   { return new FilmYear(year); }
   public static FilmYear Parse(string year)
   { return new FilmYear(Int32.parse(year)); }
   public overide string ToString()
   { return yr.ToString(); }
   //etc... you can add: 
   //  - operator overloads to add subtract years to the value,
   //  - conversion operator overloads to implicitly/(or explicitly) 
   //    convert datetimes to FilmYears, as appropriate
   //  - overload equality and comparison operators ... 
}
```

Usage

```
 FilmYear avatarYear = FilmYear.ThisYear; 
 FilmYear casablancaYear = FilmYear.Parse(1943);
```

Comment: Thanks out of curiosity, why didn't you make a public constructor?

Comment: Two reasons..  1) It standardizes the access syntax to more consistently resemble that of an enum, (through static factory methods) and 2) to force all initializations to go through that factory method...  In this simplified example there is little impact, but as this structure becomes more complex, it allows a single common point of entry to be more easily managed.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for casual users, an int (or class based on int) is correct.

If you are doing a 'real' filmography, you'll need both an int and a string: the int for sorting and searching, with the string containing the "truth" of cases where the data is incomplete or tentative ("1958?").

This is also why you shouldn't use a Date or DateTime: there's no way to distinguish between "1/1/1958" and "sometime in 1958".

Answer (score 0):

I think to properly answer that question, you need to supply a little more context. For what kind of application? Is this information going to be stored in a database? What kinds of queries do you expect users to perform against the data? Things like that.

Comment: Thansk, it's a movie collection application. So the year will be in an xml already present that I will read and give the option to sort movies by year, or show movies from a certain year range, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to keep track of the `Year`, then keep it a `int`.  If you're tracking the release date/production date, then use `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity using an `int` is the most direct option; if there are any special methods for the data then creating a `Year` type and encapsulating all behaviors would be a clean and simple solution--if you go that route you can store the value as either an `int` or `DateTime` and offer .ToInt(), .ToDateTime(), methods and others to handle all use-cases.